# correct way to scrape this table (using scrapy / xpath)

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Given a table (unknown number of `<tr>` but always three `<td>`, and sometimes containing a strikethrough (`<s>`) of the first element which should be captured as additional item (with value 0 or 1))

```
<table id="my_id">
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><s>B1</s></td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Where scraping should yield `[[A1,A2,A3,0],[B1,B2,B3,1], ...]`, I currently try along those lines:

```
my_xpath = response.xpath("//table[@id='my_id']")
for my_cell in my_xpath.xpath(".//tr"):
    print('record 0:', my_cell.xpath(".//td")[0])
    print('record 1:', my_cell.xpath(".//td")[1])
    print('record 2:', my_cell.xpath(".//td")[2])
```

And in principle it works (e.g. by adding a pipeline after `add_xpath()`), just I am sure there is a more natural and elegant way to do this.

Comment: It looks elegant enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try contains :

```
my_xpath = response.xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'my_id')]").getall()
```

Comment: This returns the entire table as one long list element and is not helpful.